# CRUD PUG mongodb Eliminar, Editar

Tags: api, crud, matriz, pug, datos

espero me puedan ayudar, tengo un problema con una petición delete, hice todas mis priebas en postman y funcionan perfecto, el problema es cuando intento hacer la peticion desde pug, deja de funcionar y marca un error en la url, mi codigo es este:

```
recetaCTRL.eliminar = async(req, res) => {
const id = req.params.id;
await receta.findByIdAndRemove({ _id: id });
//res.redirect('lista')
res.json({
    mensaje: "receta eliminada",
});
```

};

y el error es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi codigo de pug es este:

```
a.card-footer-item(href='/edit/'+receta.id) Edit
        a.card-footer-item(href="/eliminar/" + receta._id ) Delete
```

muchas gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

te falta el **/** después del eliminar, tu código debería ser así

```
a.card-footer-item(href="/eliminar/" + receta._id )
```

Comment: gracias, pero da el mismo error

Comment: estas usando el metodo GET o el metodo DELETE?, recuerda que si usas metodos HTTP debes configurar tu solicitud para que apunte al metodo correcto

Comment: metodo delete, lo tengo configurado en mi router asi: router.delete("/eliminar/:id", recetaController.eliminar);

Comment: ok, lo que pasa es que mediante href solo puedes acceder a métodos GET, lo que debes hacer es incluir una función en el href y hacer que esa función invoque un fetch con el método DELETE, puedes hacerlo asi: href="javascript:MyFunction()"